# How to change color of shaded area in highcharts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I want same color of line and area of a time series chart in highcharts. I am attaching the link of jsfiddle
here the shaded area and line color of chart is blue but i want with this hex code #70843A. can anyone help me? https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-time-series

```js
Highcharts.getJSON(
  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/samples/data/usdeur.json",
  function (data) {
    Highcharts.chart("container", {
      chart: {
        zoomType: "x",
      },
      title: {
        text: "USD to EUR exchange rate over time",
      },
      subtitle: {
        text:
          document.ontouchstart === undefined
            ? "Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in"
            : "Pinch the chart to zoom in",
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: "datetime",
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: "Exchange rate",
        },
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      plotOptions: {
        area: {
          fillColor: {
            linearGradient: {
              x1: 0,
              y1: 0,
              x2: 0,
              y2: 1,
            },
            stops: [
              [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
              [
                1,
                Highcharts.color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0])
                  .setOpacity(0)
                  .get("rgba"),
              ],
            ],
          },
          marker: {
            radius: 2,
          },
          lineWidth: 1,
          states: {
            hover: {
              lineWidth: 1,
            },
          },
          threshold: null,
        },
      },

      series: [
        {
          type: "area",
          name: "USD to EUR",
          data: data,
        },
      ],
    });
  }
);
```

```css
.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
  min-width: 360px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}
.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 1em 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #555;
}
.highcharts-data-table th {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}
.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
  background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <p class="highcharts-description">
    Highcharts has extensive support for time series, and will adapt
    intelligently to the input data. Click and drag in the chart to zoom in and
    inspect the data.
  </p>
</figure>
```

Comment: Hi @NIHAL KUMAR, Could you explain what exactly you want to achieve? Here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/theu0z5x/ is an example with inverted colors and used `#70843A`.

Comment: i want that you can see in this chart there is a line and area so i want line with #70843A color and the area will also in this hex code theme but must be lighter to deeper as in this jsfiddle blue one is happening

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/94hjp7mt/ ? To change line color, use `color` property for series.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right, you don't want that gradient.

Highcharts offers it, and its in your working example, specifically

```
plotOptions: {
        area: {
          fillColor: {
            linearGradient: {
              x1: 0,
              y1: 0,
              x2: 0,
              y2: 1,
            },
            stops: [
              [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
              [
                1,
                Highcharts.color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0])
                  .setOpacity(0)
                  .get("rgba"),
              ],
            ],
          }
```

This can be updated, towards the end with the setOpacity..

```
[1, Highcharts.color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(1).get('rgba')]
```

As it says, you just set the opacity to 1. Full block colour.

If you just want to change the colour itself, you can just set the fill colour to a CSS colour..

`fillColor: '#FF0000',`

[Ugly Red JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s6mxjvd8/)

Documentation is here : [Highcharts Documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/index)

And if you want the line colour etc set to the HEX you metnioned.

You can set `lineColor` in the marker ..

[Green LineColour](https://jsfiddle.net/nqzjvxbc/)

The documentation is very well laid out.

Comment: Actually it is showing solid color for each line and area of chart but you can see in my given link the area color is going to light in bottom i want that type and line color should be some bold so it can show the line of chart clearly plz help on this

Comment: So read the documentation, even keep your own code, and just update the color. I'm not doing everything for yah :) I'll give you a hint though, keep the `linearGradient` that you have.